# Repeatedly remove a substring quickly

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve the USACO problem [Censoring (Bronze)](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=526), which was the first problem for the 2015 February contest. My solution works for some test cases, but then times out for test cases 7-15. I expected it to run with O(n) time complexity because of the `while` loop, which should work, but it didn't.

Problem:

> Farmer John has purchased a subscription to Good Hooveskeeping
> magazine for his cows, so they have plenty of material to read while
> waiting around in the barn during milking sessions. Unfortunately, the
> latest issue contains a rather inappropriate article on how to cook
> the perfect steak, which FJ would rather his cows not see (clearly,
> the magazine is in need of better editorial oversight).
>
> FJ has taken all of the text from the magazine to create the string S
> of length at most 10^6 characters. From this, he would like to remove
> occurrences of a substring T of length <= 100 characters to censor the
> inappropriate content. To do this, Farmer John finds the *first*
> occurrence of T in S and deletes it. He then repeats the process
> again, deleting the first occurrence of T again, continuing until
> there are no more occurrences of T in S. Note that the deletion of one
> occurrence might create a new occurrence of T that didn't exist
> before.
>
> Please help FJ determine the final contents of S after censoring is
> complete.
>
> INPUT FORMAT: (file censor.in) The first line will contain S. The
> second line will contain T. The length of T will be at most that of S,
> and all characters of S and T will be lower-case alphabet characters
> (in the range a..z).
>
> OUTPUT FORMAT: (file censor.out) The string S after all deletions are
> complete. It is guaranteed that S will not become empty during the
> deletion process.

```py
# Censoring (Bronze)
input = open('censor.in', 'r').read().split('\n')
s = input[0]
c = input[1]
l = len(c)
while True:
    try:
        i = s.index(c)
        s = s[:i] + s[i + l:]
    except:
        break
output = open('censor.out', 'w')
output.write(s)
output.close()
```

How do I speed up the code? I tried to use Numba, but Numba doesn't work in [USACO IDE](https://ide.usaco.guide/NXQs8hkV3sWOtNYsvyj).
This was supposed to solve all the test cases under the time limit, which is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assumption: `len(c)` << `len(s)`.
For example, when censoring "moo".

---

You asked if one can

> speed up python

but really this is a matter of "speeding up an algorithm".
That is, you have *accidentally* fallen into a higher
time complexity than necessary.

> I expected it to run with O(n) time complexity

Certainly the `while` loop is linear in size of article string `s`.
But you're restarting that linear `.index()` search
from the beginning each time, leading to
nested loop \$O(N × M)\$ behavior
if the censored `c` appears \$M\$ times within the article.
Given \$M << N\$ an efficient algorithm should see
article size dominate the cost,
with negligible contribution from the censoring operations.

In addition to `.index()` being linear in `len(s)`,
notice that producing a new immutable `str` with string catenation
is *also* \$O(len(s))\$.

---

```
input = open('censor.in', 'r').read().split('\n')
```

A more natural method to call here would have been
[.readlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines).

Rather than leaving an open file descriptor resource
lying around until end-of-scope,
prefer to use a `with` context handler
so it closes when you're done with it.

Shadowing the builtin `input()` is *definitely* not Best Practice.

```py
s = input[0]
c = input[1]
```

Usually we give `0` and `1` a pass when it comes to calling out
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).
But here it obscures Author's Intent, there's no need for such cryptic indexes.
Prefer a tuple unpack:

```py
s, c = input
```

Also, even though these are local variables in
a very short piece of code,
*please* consider using more informative names
such as `article` and `censored`.

---

```py
    except:
```

No.

Do not use "bare" `except`,
as it will sometimes swallow exceptions such as `KeyboardInterrupt`
which we really want to be propagated.
Prefer to habitually write `except Exception:`

But here we know perfectly well what we're hoping to trap,
so spell it out for the Gentle Reader:

```py
    except ValueError:  # substring not found
```

---

```py
        i = s.index(c)
```

Suppose we have a million-character article,
and we've already deleted a thousand instances of "moo".
This `.index()` call is super expensive -- it's trolling
through roughly a megabyte of article text that we've
already repeatedly scanned before.
We *know* there's a giant prefix which is entirely "moo"-free.

[.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)
offers an optional `start` parameter.
Use it.
You'll have to maintain another temp variable.
Since deleting "moo" from "momooo" can expose another instance,
you should conservatively use `j = s.index(c, j) - len(c)`.
This will *still* yield \$O(len(s))\$ complexity,
given our assumption.

---

```py
        s = s[:i] + s[i + l:]
```

As noted above, this is linear in `len(s)`.
Rather than reading a pair of giant immutable strings
and writing a new giant immutable string, prefer a
[tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming))
approach.

Start with this import:

```
from array import array
```

Spend \$O(n)\$ time copying article text into an array.
If articles are guaranteed ASCII text then we can
get away with a `byte` array, else we need an array of `int`s.

Implement your own version of `.index()` which

- compares against article text in the array, and
- knows that it must skip over (ignore) any tombstone entries

Now "deleting" a censored string from the article
is a matter of overwriting each character with a
[sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)
tombstone value such as `0`.

Finally at the end you'll need to do linear work with `"".join( ... )`
to copy out non-sentinel Unicode code points,
producing the final sanitized article that is safe for cows to read.

Comment: Can you give me the full code you are talking about? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> It timed out for test cases 7-15. I expected it to run with O(n) time complexity because of the while loop, which should work, but it didn't. What's wrong?

Lets look at the [Common Sequence Operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> | Operation | Result | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | `s + t` | the concatenation of s and t | (6)(7) |
>
> ...
>
> 6. Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object. This means that building up a sequence by repeated concatenation will have a quadratic runtime cost in the total sequence length. To get a linear runtime cost, you must switch to one of the alternatives below:
>
>    - if concatenating [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) objects, you can build a list and use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) at the end or else write to an [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) instance and retrieve its value when complete

You should build a list using [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), then build the string with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

<sub>**Note**: untested</sub>

```py
output: list[str] = []
prev = 0
try:
    while True:
        curr = s.index(c, prev)
        output.append(s[prev:curr])
        prev = curr + len(c)
except ValueError:
    output.append(s[prev:])
s = "".join(output)
```

---

Even better you can actually just use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```py
s = s.replace(c, "")
```

Comment: `prev = curr + len(c)` doesn't account for occurrences appearing after deletion. `check = curr - len(c) + 1` needs a whole new logic to assemble the output.

Comment: @greybeard Ah yeah I didn't see "Note that the deletion of one occurrence might create a new occurrence of T that didn't exist before." in the description. A simple approach is to just wrap `s.replace(c, "")` in a while loop until the replace does nothing... A performant approach on the other hand may be a little more intricate to write.

Comment: (I've come up with two stacks… and ditched it: to much *additional space* (especially with Python). A counter for *incomplete possible censored words* is enough.)

Comment: @greybeard I'd probably go with `(s[curr - len(c):curr] + s[curr + len(c):curr + 2*len(c)]).index(c)` in an inner while loop. The algorithm becomes a little more complicated on the whole. I'd use `str.index` over a Trie because Python's so slow I'd expect the `str.index` to perform better, with a lower complexity score.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, the issue in the original code is that you are constructing a lot of big strings. Each indexing operation is O(C), each rebuilding is O(C), and you may need to rebuild C times. So your original code is O(C²). It may also be helpful for you to separate the solver from the input handling, as I tried to do below:

```
def solver(string_s, censor_t):
    c = len(string_s)
    d = len(censor_t)
    last_symbol = censor_t[-1]

    # emulate a stack; end is the # of symbols in the stack
    stack_arr = [None] * c
    stack_end = 0

    for symbol in string_s:
        # emulate pushing symbol to the stack
        stack_arr[stack_end] = symbol
        stack_end += 1
        if stack_end >= d and symbol == last_symbol:
            if "".join(stack_arr[(stack_end - d):stack_end]) == censor_t:
                # emulate popping d elements from the stack
                stack_end -= d

    return "".join(stack_arr[:stack_end])


line1, line2 = open('censor.in', 'r').read().split('\n')
output = open('censor.out', 'w')
output.write(solver(line1, line2))
output.close()
```

### Reasoning

Let D be the length of the censor T and let C be the length of the string S. Create an empty list called stack (which is what we’ll treat it as). Add S to stack, 1 character at a time. Check if the last D elements (characters) of stack would form T. If so, pop the last D characters of stack. Repeat until S is completely traversed. Then print out stack. Since each check takes D comparisons and we do at most C checks / adds / removes, this is O(CD) time.

Further improvements:

1. only check whenever you add the last character of T to stack.
2. only check whenever stack is of size D or greater.
3. create a dictionary counting the frequency of each character in stack and only check when stack has enough of each character to make T.

### Testing

I put 2000000 'a' and then 1000000 'b' with the censor 'aab'. The initial code takes over 222.49 seconds. The revised takes 0.64 seconds.

```
output = open("censor2.in", "w")
value = "aab"
output.write(''.join([char*1000000 for char in value]))
output.write("\naab")
output.close()
```

### Note

If we were in a language like C, you could also achieve O(1) space by cannibalizing the original string to make a stack. Do you see how?

Comment: Thanks! This also works. Could you show me how to make the original string into a stack in C++?

Comment: Sure, I will give it a shot when I get the time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having some IDE issues. In C, strings are just arrays of characters. So you could delete the declaration of stack_arr and use string_s whenever you subsequently use stack_arr. The pseudo-stack will never run out of space because string_s initially held all the characters to begin with.